# I have an activity on which i have placed a spinner

Tags: android

That activity can be opened in two ways. If that activity is opened directly, the spinner should not appear. When it is opened through another intent, it should show a spinner including all of its content. What should I do?

Comment: make to separate activity according to the use .

Comment: you can use bundle. pass boolean and on receiving use it to setVisibility of spinner.

Comment: can you write me a sample code?? Please

Answer (score 1):

If opened directly means it is the main activity, then inside your activity:

```
boolean showSpinner = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("SHOW_SPINNER", false);

spinner.setVisibility(showSpinner ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

When you are calling through intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("SHOW_SPINNER", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

So, when the intent extra is missing, you'll know it hasn't been called from another activity.

Comment: By directly i mean I am using an intent there too.... In both ways activity is opened by using intent

Comment: Well, it still answers your question then. Just pass the other time a false.

Comment: It should work. Make sure that you have the right reference to the spinner and that the keys - "SHOW_SPINNER" are the same.